# Error from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

Tags: django, virtualenv, wsgi

Выставляю на хостинг(jino) django проект и уже неделю решаю ошибки, но к этой не знаю даже как подобраться. Понимаю, что такие вопросы не следует задавать, но мне некуда больше обратиться. Надеюсь хоть у кого то есть идеи:

```
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201] mod_wsgi (pid=67587): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/users/m/marselabdullin/domains/caparolcenterspb.ru/django.wsgi'.
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201] mod_wsgi (pid=67587): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/users/m/marselabdullin/domains/caparolcenterspb.ru/django.wsgi'.
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]   File "/home/users/m/marselabdullin/domains/caparolcenterspb.ru/django.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]     from wsgi import application
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]   File "/home/users/m/marselabdullin/caparol_center_spb_decision/caparol_center_spb_decision/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]   File "/home/users/m/marselabdullin/caparol_center_spb_decision/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]   File "/home/users/m/marselabdullin/caparol_center_spb_decision/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]   File "/home/users/m/marselabdullin/caparol_center_spb_decision/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]     self._setup(name)
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]   File "/home/users/m/marselabdullin/caparol_center_spb_decision/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]   File "/home/users/m/marselabdullin/caparol_center_spb_decision/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Apr 06 19:15:28 2020] [error] [client 94.130.134.201] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caparol_center_spb_decision'
```

wsgi.py
import os

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'caparol_center_spb_decision.settings.pro')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: покажите свой wsgi.py файл

Comment: Добавил, вроде стандартный по умолчанию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделайте так в своем файле wsgi

```
import os, sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/var/www/project/backend')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: в sys нужно путь на диске указывать или относительный?

Comment: @МарсельАбдуллин относительный

Comment: не совсем понял относительно чего(так '../backends')?

Comment: @МарсельАбдуллин `sys.path.append('/home/users/m/marselabdullin/domains/caparolcenterspb.ru/')`

Comment: спасибо тебе большущее, добрый человек, без тебя я бы наверное так и застрял на неделю, поддержка то не отвечает

Comment: там возникли еще ошибки, но их уже вполне можно было загуглить)

Comment: @МарсельАбдуллин не за что)
если ответ помог не забывайте поставить галочку возле него)